# Generate a random number and sort odd and even numbers using JOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

my first question here. My assignment is to generate a random number between 1 and 10, 20 times. After that I'm supposed to somehow write the numbers into two separated strings for Odd and Even numbers. We're also supposed to count how many total numbers we had for each group of numbers. This is what I have so far, I need help on how to display the separated numbers. I would like to use JOptionPane as well please, but any help is appreciated!

```
package lab5arudy;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Lab5ARudy
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   int randomNumber = 0;
   int evenNumbers = 0;
   int oddNumbers = 0;  

   String evenNums;
   String oddNums;


 for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
   {
       randomNumber = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 10);

        if (randomNumber % 2 ==0)
               {                 
                  evenNumbers++;               
               }
            else
                oddNumbers++;       

    }


          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Even Numbers: " + evenNumbers);
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Even Numbers: " + oddNumbers );


      }

}
```

Comment: What do you want the JOptionPane to do? As input? Or output?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you just need to add all your random numbers to lists so that you can print them afterwards. Something like the following:

```
Random rand = new Random();
List<Integer> odds = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> evens = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    int next = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
    if (next % 2 == 0)
        evens.add(next);
    else
        odds.add(next);
}
showMessageDialog("Even :" + evens + " (" + evens.size() + ")");
showMessageDialog("Odds :" + odds + " (" + odds.size() + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int randomNumber;

    int evenNumbers = 0;
    int oddNumbers = 0;

    String evenNums = "";//initialize empty strings
    String oddNums = "";//initialize empty strings

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        randomNumber = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        if (randomNumber % 2 == 0) {
            evenNumbers++;
            if (evenNums.equals("")) {//if the evenNums is empty, append the number
                evenNums = evenNums + randomNumber;
            } else {
                evenNums = evenNums + "," + randomNumber;//if the evenNums is not empty, append the number with a , in between
            }
        } else {
            oddNumbers++;
            if (oddNums.equals("")) {
                oddNums = oddNums + randomNumber;//if the oddNums is empty, append the number
            } else {
                oddNums = oddNums + "," + randomNumber;//if the oddNums is not empty, append the number with a , in between
            }
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Even Numbers: " + evenNumbers+"\n"+evenNums);//Show the even numbers
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Odd Numbers: " + oddNumbers+"\n"+oddNums);//Show the odd numbers
}
```